Group_by + summarize not working (Looks like a bug in the package dplyr)
My question is rather problematic since I know the code is completely fine. I leave you below what I am doing (very simple stuff):
Means_region <- data %>% 
  mutate(year_fctr = case_when(edate < "1994-12-31" ~ "1990-1994",
                               edate > "1995-01-01" & edate < "1999-12-31" ~ "1995-1999",
                               edate > "2000-01-01" & edate < "2004-12-31" ~ "2000-2004",
                               edate > "2005-01-01" & edate < "2009-12-31" ~ "2005-2009",
                               edate > "2010-01-01" & edate < "2014-12-31" ~ "2010-2014",
                               edate > "2015-01-01" & edate < "2019-12-31" ~ "2015-2019",
                               edate > "2020-01-01" ~ "2020-2022")
         ) %>% 
  group_by(region, year_fctr) %>% 
  summarise(pol=mean(pol))


The issue is that even if the code creates perfectly fine the column year_fctr using mutate() and case_when() (I have checked it just using the mutate and the column exists), it just will not group it based on that existing column. The worst part of all of this is that it did work the day before yesterday and yesterday loading again the file and the code it won't work.
I have reset RStudio, cleaning and reloading all the objects in the environment and even resetting my computer and it will not cooperate, it just won't.
dput() from my dataframe of the beginning (taking the first ten rows head(data,10):
structure(list(countryname = c("Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Norway"
), edate = structure(c(7927, 9026, 10490, 11945, 13408, 14871, 
16327, 17783, 19246, 8656), class = "Date"), date = c(199109L, 
199409L, 199809L, 200209L, 200609L, 201009L, 201409L, 201809L, 
202209L, 199309L), pervote = c(3.383, 5.023, 4.5, 4.646, 5.244, 
7.34, 6.889, 4.414, 5.08262535054372, 7.907), per108_bal = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00255657175901268, 0, 0), per110_bal = c(0.153842292827385, 
0.0862068965517241, 0.127269633062352, 0.0673106693912936, 0.0180167323712517, 
0.0128146991148956, 0.00659394734683835, 0, 0, 0.0599817523618919
), per107_bal = c(0.0769295119543576, 0, 0.0909031405045229, 
0.125007740417363, 0.0360334647425034, 0, 0.0230952185680308, 
0.0127828587950634, 0.0540516084274662, 0.166288960178945), per109_bal = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00910910321688201), per104_bal = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00511314351802535, 0.0270258042137331, 0.0113900579803985
), per105_bal = c(0.0769295119543576, 0.0344827586206897, 0.072732985115658, 
0.0480834726608459, 0.0180167323712517, 0.0320451453620194, 0.00990732387435414, 
0.0255809352791685, 0.0432382704691812, 0.0242958471907467), 
    per504_bal = c(0, 0.0689655172413793, 0.127269633062352, 
    0.182689330608706, 0.297311760823418, 0.198720209603467, 
    0.181513983433117, 0.163681463332978, 0.162169906646357, 
    0.209568237337022), per505_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.00303146245989934), per506_bal = c(0, 0, 0.0181832462789145, 
    0.0384543934608954, 0.0360334647425034, 0.166675064241447, 
    0.250832444845403, 0.0920670187025398, 0.0540516084274662, 
    0.0698560791123407), per507_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), per203_bal = c(0, 0.0172413793103448, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.0108133379582849, 0), per204_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), per301_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0.0288407950956716, 
    0.0540501971137551, 0.0192304462471238, 0.00990732387435414, 
    0, 0, 0.0174676987373812), per302_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00379668599346617), per603_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0280925331842129), per604_bal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00659394734683835, 0.00255657175901268, 
    0.0162124662554481, 0.00379668599346617), per607_bal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00641574713222821, 0.0462068399901583, 0.0306940787971939, 
    0.0162124662554481, 0.0470759631515437), per608_bal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00766971527703803, 0, 0.00910910321688201
    ), per601_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00990732387435414, 
    0.0102262870360507, 0, 0), per602_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.0429098663167391, 0.0434769375922573, 0, 0), per406_bal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00456190952703299), per407_bal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000765223533566825), per401_bal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00990732387435414, 0.00255657175901268, 
    0.00539912829716319, 0), per402_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0.0673106693912936, 
    0.063058563299381, 0.0961522312356192, 0.0230952185680308, 
    0.0204677917611432, 0, 0.0220148924272302), per414_bal = c(0.0192240124479245, 
    0.172413793103448, 0.036366492557829, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00303146245989934
    ), per403_bal = c(0.0192240124479245, 0.137931034482759, 
    0.109086386783437, 0.00961359836522385, 0.0180167323712517, 
    0.0192304462471238, 0.00329697367341918, 0, 0.00539912829716319, 
    0.000765223533566825), per404_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00641574713222821, 
    0.00329697367341918, 0, 0, 0), per405_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.0180167323712517, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), per409_bal = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000765223533566825), per412_bal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.063058563299381, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.022780115960797
    ), per413_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00659394734683835, 
    0, 0, 0.00303146245989934), per415_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00303146245989934), per410_bal = c(0.0192240124479245, 
    0.0172413793103448, 0.0181832462789145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0162124662554481, 
    0.0220148924272302), per416_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0627081112113508, 
    0.166238035091991, 0.227034853032108, 0.077449451099273), 
    per501_bal = c(0.634626645920126, 0.46551724137931, 0.40000523635602, 
    0.432689330608706, 0.306320127009044, 0.391024672074705, 
    0.231034199950791, 0.383637940742319, 0.237848190990393, 
    0.164022721252612), per605_bal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0720669294850069, 
    0.0512755916091433, 0.0693020585581891, 0.0306940787971939, 
    0.124330764474339, 0.0129057892103482), per605_1_bal = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0693020585581891, 0.0306940787971939, 
    0.124330764474339, NA), per605_2_bal = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0.00329697367341918, 0, 0, NA), region = c("Northern", 
    "Northern", "Northern", "Northern", "Northern", "Northern", 
    "Northern", "Northern", "Northern", "Northern"), year = c("1991", 
    "1994", "1998", "2002", "2006", "2010", "2014", "2018", "2022", 
    "1993"), pos_euro = c(-0.153842292827385, -0.0862068965517241, 
    -0.127269633062352, -0.0673106693912936, -0.0180167323712517, 
    -0.0128146991148956, -0.00659394734683835, 0.00255657175901268, 
    0, -0.0599817523618919), pos_inter = c(0.0769295119543576, 
    0, 0.0909031405045229, 0.125007740417363, 0.0360334647425034, 
    0, 0.0230952185680308, 0.0127828587950634, 0.0540516084274662, 
    0.157179856962063), pos_def = c(-0.0769295119543576, -0.0344827586206897, 
    -0.072732985115658, -0.0480834726608459, -0.0180167323712517, 
    -0.0320451453620194, -0.00990732387435414, -0.0204677917611432, 
    -0.0162124662554481, -0.0129057892103482), pos_welf = c(0, 
    0.0689655172413793, 0.127269633062352, 0.182689330608706, 
    0.297311760823418, 0.198720209603467, 0.181513983433117, 
    0.163681463332978, 0.162169906646357, 0.206536774877123), 
    pos_edu = c(0, 0, 0.0181832462789145, 0.0384543934608954, 
    0.0360334647425034, 0.166675064241447, 0.250832444845403, 
    0.0920670187025398, 0.0540516084274662, 0.0698560791123407
    ), pos_const = c(0, 0.0172413793103448, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.0108133379582849, 0), pos_reg = c(0, 0, 0, 0.0288407950956716, 
    0.0540501971137551, 0.0192304462471238, 0.00990732387435414, 
    0, 0, 0.013671012743915), pos_tradlib = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -0.00659394734683835, -0.00255657175901268, -0.0162124662554481, 
    0.0242958471907467), pos_multicul = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00641574713222821, 
    0.0462068399901583, 0.0230243635201558, 0.0162124662554481, 
    0.0379668599346617), pos_nat = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.033002542442385, 
    -0.0332506505562065, 0, 0), pos_prtct = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00379668599346617), pos_laissezplan = c(0, 
    0.0344827586206897, -0.0727198942256084, 0.0576970710260697, 
    -0.0360334647425034, 0.0705060378562671, 0.0198146477487083, 
    0.0230243635201558, 0, -0.00532713306059982), pos_env = c(-0.615402633472201, 
    -0.448275862068966, -0.381821990077105, -0.432689330608706, 
    -0.306320127009044, -0.391024672074705, -0.293742311162142, 
    -0.54987597583431, -0.448670577767053, -0.219457279924655
    ), pos_secur = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0720669294850069, 0.0512755916091433, 
    0.0660050848847699, 0.0306940787971939, 0.124330764474339, 
    0.0129057892103482), sal_euro = c(0.153842292827385, 0.0862068965517241, 
    0.127269633062352, 0.0673106693912936, 0.0180167323712517, 
    0.0128146991148956, 0.00659394734683835, 0.00255657175901268, 
    0, 0.0599817523618919), sal_inter = c(0.0769295119543576, 
    0, 0.0909031405045229, 0.125007740417363, 0.0360334647425034, 
    0, 0.0230952185680308, 0.0127828587950634, 0.0540516084274662, 
    0.175398063395827), sal_def = c(0.0769295119543576, 0.0344827586206897, 
    0.072732985115658, 0.0480834726608459, 0.0180167323712517, 
    0.0320451453620194, 0.00990732387435414, 0.0306940787971939, 
    0.0702640746829143, 0.0356859051711452), sal_welf = c(0, 
    0.0689655172413793, 0.127269633062352, 0.182689330608706, 
    0.297311760823418, 0.198720209603467, 0.181513983433117, 
    0.163681463332978, 0.162169906646357, 0.212599699796921), 
    sal_edu = c(0, 0, 0.0181832462789145, 0.0384543934608954, 
    0.0360334647425034, 0.166675064241447, 0.250832444845403, 
    0.0920670187025398, 0.0540516084274662, 0.0698560791123407
    ), sal_const = c(0, 0.0172413793103448, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.0108133379582849, 0), sal_reg = c(0, 0, 0, 0.0288407950956716, 
    0.0540501971137551, 0.0192304462471238, 0.00990732387435414, 
    0, 0, 0.0212643847308473), sal_tradlib = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.00659394734683835, 0.00255657175901268, 0.0162124662554481, 
    0.031889219177679), sal_multicul = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00641574713222821, 
    0.0462068399901583, 0.0383637940742319, 0.0162124662554481, 
    0.0561850663684257), sal_nat = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0528171901910933, 
    0.053703224628308, 0, 0), sal_prtct = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.00532713306059982), sal_laissezplan = c(0.038448024895849, 
    0.310344827586207, 0.145452879341266, 0.0769242677565174, 
    0.162150591341265, 0.121798424614971, 0.0461904371360617, 
    0.0230243635201558, 0.0107982565943264, 0.0554198428348589
    ), sal_env = c(0.65385065836805, 0.482758620689655, 0.418188482634934, 
    0.432689330608706, 0.306320127009044, 0.391024672074705, 
    0.293742311162142, 0.54987597583431, 0.48109551027795, 0.263487064779115
    ), sal_secur = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0720669294850069, 0.0512755916091433, 
    0.0725990322316083, 0.0306940787971939, 0.124330764474339, 
    0.0129057892103482), mean_pos_euro = c(0.0404361358040147, 
    0.0480363461480908, 0.0170220063948794, 0.018727122564046, 
    0.00538808219373917, 0.00658559488995673, 0.00350714652845766, 
    0.0101128077847298, 0.00373485709176495, 0.0105472299278959
    ), mean_pos_inter = c(0.101206010823922, 0.0654061309668344, 
    0.0573142114021365, 0.0996268998338684, 0.0308219362264086, 
    0.0273638026244262, 0.0253366544457652, 0.025677921475989, 
    0.020053434775811, 0.113160207665325), mean_pos_def = c(-0.00445667220872397, 
    -0.00691313408409361, -0.0111580658887506, -0.00266497640598704, 
    0.0033722213429837, 0.00517196450244125, 0.0230884629829038, 
    0.0223213891670414, 0.0337724951671837, 0.0170737655398906
    ), mean_pos_welf = c(0.0955760782947446, 0.0491786352684619, 
    0.134720127683514, 0.139873786512013, 0.245743924029886, 
    0.270878654847156, 0.221332473888756, 0.216870326707365, 
    0.23037102643583, 0.110456681118002), mean_pos_edu = c(0.0422358974915196, 
    0.0336899136392136, 0.0900154092134119, 0.1068205673599, 
    0.117690762687617, 0.140876796501983, 0.157814699216243, 
    0.107806156963104, 0.084771692956725, 0.0794119363921141), 
    mean_pos_const = c(0.00240358912214421, 0.00246305418719212, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.000749739991613986, 0.00388068444820163, 
    0.00163555090314125), mean_pos_reg = c(0.0141917777345324, 
    0.0111002690880246, 0.0477885018709644, 0.0218850827825929, 
    0.0271937450200291, 0.0149780111154722, 0.0021732084523248, 
    0.000434175375494105, 0.00618337848305643, 0.0472509802244062
    ), mean_pos_tradlib = c(0.0345396003140203, 0.0378114798624833, 
    0.0241161588961318, 0.0465901079299324, 0.0252142439253487, 
    0.0325166258575727, -0.00327025895660341, 0.0089414255126401, 
    -0.00650404779335592, 0.0609923715866183), mean_pos_multicul = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.0030693494666013, 0.00544836804447179, -0.00284347951581304, 
    0.00997918219120811, -0.0283611122579275, -0.0216871883800512, 
    0.0163256903737892), mean_pos_nat = c(0.0228146034646482, 
    0.00948545000965647, 0, 0.00119712780575803, 0.0173747891724639, 
    0.0233458495989161, -0.0170253758785428, 0.0267910060744619, 
    0.0221192500306537, 0.0104022961990873), mean_pos_prtct = c(0, 
    0, 0, -0.00982979796123083, -0.00275662391361668, -0.00273383656086004, 
    -0.00803142055243403, -0.00276918899400266, -0.00717491644512924, 
    -0.00618615955878603), mean_pos_laissezplan = c(0.198961558244306, 
    0.264756681086296, 0.2114493593512, 0.142303569931153, -0.00123888931418084, 
    0.064055787813, 0.0525403476282539, 0.0253875999395252, 0.0217444443508756, 
    0.0923980577133026), mean_pos_env = c(-0.222320379650192, 
    -0.128394356251492, -0.120356559470918, -0.173768791906174, 
    -0.123231884978827, -0.18090793470031, -0.182462617948571, 
    -0.173369283883448, -0.167809266855446, -0.15402820754184
    ), mean_pos_secur = c(0.0421803173790586, 0.0179864617446783, 
    0.0496980555581064, 0.0658599594917766, 0.0830105489614746, 
    0.0640785618856314, 0.0790176341169412, 0.129025624283268, 
    0.196959628657995, 0.0184279910294444), mean_sal_euro = c(0.0929834745456625, 
    0.103812462872433, 0.0783131820482527, 0.055091807735765, 
    0.0249043301273878, 0.0239243670761762, 0.014006300998206, 
    0.022840333059475, 0.00952830966914289, 0.0474607561478726
    ), mean_sal_inter = c(0.101206010823922, 0.0654061309668344, 
    0.0573142114021365, 0.101613325922264, 0.0308219362264086, 
    0.0273638026244262, 0.037849230867531, 0.0311806956484329, 
    0.0222237487191981, 0.125568694029407), mean_sal_def = c(0.0218166589567979, 
    0.0129087526705112, 0.0111580658887506, 0.0110731586399689, 
    0.0135107902048928, 0.0231164198966239, 0.0352171325654738, 
    0.0450392592385245, 0.0501110731670185, 0.0428230907546493
    ), mean_sal_welf = c(0.0955760782947446, 0.0491786352684619, 
    0.134720127683514, 0.143400202300806, 0.267992434331611, 
    0.281039884521543, 0.255387581523303, 0.251394862175024, 
    0.253662039372808, 0.14009330065814), mean_sal_edu = c(0.0422358974915196, 
    0.0336899136392136, 0.0900154092134119, 0.1068205673599, 
    0.117690762687617, 0.140876796501983, 0.158919290412965, 
    0.108502477312454, 0.084771692956725, 0.0833169730518998), 
    mean_sal_const = c(0.00240358912214421, 0.00246305418719212, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0016055647422127, 0.00388068444820163, 0.00163555090314125
    ), mean_sal_reg = c(0.0141917777345324, 0.0111002690880246, 
    0.0477885018709644, 0.0218850827825929, 0.0287786790489457, 
    0.0188495752977156, 0.00603244115101005, 0.00214582487669153, 
    0.0138830874939166, 0.0566212837555651), mean_sal_tradlib = c(0.0345396003140203, 
    0.0378114798624833, 0.0241161588961318, 0.0465901079299324, 
    0.0260043167796425, 0.0352067066965501, 0.0131793254621516, 
    0.0237704951987535, 0.0158366235669746, 0.0758056528011791
    ), mean_sal_multicul = c(0, 0, 0, 0.0030693494666013, 0.00780742440395134, 
    0.0203050767295434, 0.0289669020505296, 0.0591820122496133, 
    0.0286632440086366, 0.0328690285600878), mean_sal_nat = c(0.0228146034646482, 
    0.00948545000965647, 0, 0.00119712780575803, 0.0173747891724639, 
    0.0233458495989161, 0.0588822580544644, 0.0818606797934299, 
    0.0253205545178215, 0.0104022961990873), mean_sal_prtct = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.011087604405295, 0.00435244621228382, 0.00428831784578114, 
    0.00930435686378787, 0.00276918899400266, 0.00743248554233238, 
    0.010448883967899), mean_sal_laissezplan = c(0.235597333841816, 
    0.375038470455887, 0.300404143280935, 0.224174950154609, 
    0.209990306577062, 0.120357753198566, 0.103260624967218, 
    0.0559154639642559, 0.099564128416099, 0.130279841045087), 
    mean_sal_env = c(0.294454658031133, 0.281118919234624, 0.206472144157797, 
    0.208136756004731, 0.167761235266259, 0.217246888126545, 
    0.198188921508806, 0.181185583122314, 0.187202114994835, 
    0.22424665709654), mean_sal_secur = c(0.0421803173790586, 
    0.0179864617446783, 0.0496980555581064, 0.0658599594917766, 
    0.0830105489614746, 0.0640785618856314, 0.0808056335745532, 
    0.132607559624816, 0.197920213126291, 0.0184279910294444), 
    pol_euro = c(0.12082489733415, 0.101965194780124, 0.0789706069518755, 
    0.0445902709604092, 0.0194661714613817, 0.0186334904089752, 
    0.00988765784240235, 0.0230218323107435, 0.00429075497853459, 
    0.0399389113028663), pol_inter = c(0.0627844821677291, 0.0274692510352796, 
    0.0245832042993927, 0.0345255070743195, 0.00478596997674972, 
    0.00670403084654029, 0.0100368732784001, 0.0298513240469037, 
    0.00867186165955998, 0.0540250286881538), pol_def = c(0.0233471906735174, 
    0.00835828879721331, 0.0166115858614565, 0.0104227523902427, 
    0.00638846514274101, 0.0150156538983498, 0.0247107105963671, 
    0.0279414578055665, 0.0244812265026666, 0.0241485506686932
    ), pol_welf = c(0.0873439168968685, 0.0289698507603164, 0.0737381610198812, 
    0.0656647659070997, 0.118565103422695, 0.183331726941973, 
    0.20267625838291, 0.154279049072952, 0.184420159686011, 0.0664614599508951
    ), pol_edu = c(0.0272386235213555, 0.0156098663404123, 0.0285593096411532, 
    0.0695012410765138, 0.0510672344551977, 0.073444467233151, 
    0.103694834608818, 0.0506619712529666, 0.0408264054704871, 
    0.0177661546644044), pol_const = c(0.00233310013238297, 0.0019404891555624, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000580012304622843, 0.00117040053889352, 
    0.000548475208106062), pol_reg = c(0.0104756330923493, 0.0158518573891979, 
    0.0615191396223416, 0.0192176080247559, 0.0129369368751246, 
    0.0122073410020887, 0.00341459147399128, 0.000830166568196308, 
    0.00843729903346307, 0.0297634634964584), pol_tradlib = c(0.0404150455448279, 
    0.072633038703069, 0.0200087486925339, 0.0874443251250441, 
    0.025899817803368, 0.0460033405697498, 0.00710777744698461, 
    0.0307542736151476, 0.0053468007590204, 0.0985277278897992
    ), pol_multicul = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00146071281424595, 0.00252879105290296, 
    0.0278248778471243, 0.018152783138818, 0.0254026954454675, 
    0.0142637698583309, 0.0102787819217894), pol_nat = c(0.0229596623992457, 
    0.00798290787216119, 0, 0.000274215166375891, 0.00742174780607839, 
    0.0515017483218547, 0.0598085365548079, 0.0555354323081328, 
    0.0205069527159616, 0.00310324796383001), pol_prtct = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.00354527572444212, 0.00189796674798386, 0.0014556343814613, 
    0.00716639125443205, 0.000700674855103647, 0.00394873049434092, 
    0.00566911635265743), pol_laissezplan = c(0.278288813717876, 
    0.376361953696313, 0.357479936633271, 0.287281480937095, 
    0.207993954574261, 0.0623753184129893, 0.0778456285270103, 
    0.0361660789093771, 0.100237506868417, 0.173059122895247), 
    pol_env = c(0.332405632544831, 0.317219856397167, 0.195211513438994, 
    0.183434433562485, 0.111600537832815, 0.210121405966822, 
    0.195233819217862, 0.289261827141532, 0.204595055622314, 
    0.0986332280356917), pol_secur = c(0.041078200596562, 0.0141767188530247, 
    0.0257711735095036, 0.0324405769403972, 0.0731944691103037, 
    0.0409221644437707, 0.0382844246976587, 0.0669307041862785, 
    0.156172746603598, 0.00220077819367665), pol = c(0.0139175622804025, 
    0.0177160664645774, 0.0123343546293873, 0.00944119716090404, 
    0.00772721088558479, 0.00873197265152529, 0.0088344526144641, 
    0.00836357606968884, 0.00943256631379078, 0.00534241718974811
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(countryname = c("Norway", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden"), edate = structure(c(8656, 7927, 9026, 10490, 
11945, 13408, 14871, 16327, 17783, 19246), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(
    10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))

dput() is the following for the dataframe not working:
structure(list(pol = 0.00849904532770635), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

Please if you know how to get it working, specially any debugging tools so as to fix this absurd issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.
Update: I have applied @RuiBarradas solution to add the .by parameter in summarise, yet a new error has appeared.
Running traceback() as @yuk recommended gives the following output:
5: stop(simpleError(msg, call = if (p <- sys.parent(1L)) sys.call(p)))
4: stopifnot(length(rows) == 1)
3: quickdf(.data[names(cols)])
2: summarise(., pol = mean(pol), .by = c(region, year_fctr))
1: data %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(year_fctr = case_when(edate < "1994-12-31" ~ 
       "1990-1994", edate > "1995-01-01" & edate < "1999-12-31" ~ 
       "1995-1999", edate > "2000-01-01" & edate < "2004-12-31" ~ 
       "2000-2004", edate > "2005-01-01" & edate < "2009-12-31" ~ 
       "2005-2009", edate > "2010-01-01" & edate < "2014-12-31" ~ 
       "2010-2014", edate > "2015-01-01" & edate < "2019-12-31" ~ 
       "2015-2019", edate > "2020-01-01" ~ "2020-2022")) %>% summarise(pol = mean(pol), 
       .by = c(region, year_fctr))


Could you please share some reproducible data using dput?

Hey @Quinten, I added the metadata info of the whole thing (the dataframe I am creating that is), but I am not able to understand what is going on. Do you know what does it mean? Also, its counterpart is quite large so the dput() is gargantuan, it does not fit my console

No, that's not metadata, that's an instruction to recreate a data.frame with just one column, pol and just one row. Like this there is no column edate for us to test and see what is going on. Please edit the question with the output of dput(data). Or, if the data set is too big with the output of dput(head(data, 20)).

Thanks @RuiBarradas for the help, already updated the post with the info of the first dataframe. Still do not know what to look for.

Your data is already grouped. Start by ungroup()'ing it and then, instead of group_by/summarise, combine both in summarise(pol = mean(pol), .by = c(region, year_fctr)).

@RuiBarradas I have done what you said, ungrouping the data of origin and ungrouping the data just before mutating the year_fctr... but when doing both methods, the following error pops up: "Error in quickdf(.data[names(cols)]): length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE" Do not know why it has a problem with the number of rows now.


There is no quickdf in the question, is it another data set? 2) Have you seen if my answer solves the problem as posted?


After you get the error, run traceback() and show the output.

@yuk thanks for the feedback, the post is updated with the output of traceback(). I still do not understand why quickdf appears is called tho. If you know what is going on after looking the output, please let me know :)

@Th3W31rd0, which package are you loading, and are they up to date? With the newly provided traceback,  quickdf(.data[names(cols)]) is weird ; and might be linked with the retired package plyr

@VinceGreg it was the plyr package... I was working with a df for trying my code and when going to the environment where I load (with pacman) all the bulk packages, the problem came up. Do not ask me how plyr ended up in my package list, it is an old list I use when I first started checking R in uni. Thanks a lot for the help. Gotta be more careful when loading packages.

Like I say in my comment to the question, the problem seems to come from the fact that the data is already grouped.
The code below starts by ungrouping and then summarise with the argument .by to group/compute the summary statistics/ungroup all in the same instruction.
source("~/so.txt")

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

data %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(year_fctr = case_when(edate < "1994-12-31" ~ "1990-1994",
                               edate > "1995-01-01" & edate < "1999-12-31" ~ "1995-1999",
                               edate > "2000-01-01" & edate < "2004-12-31" ~ "2000-2004",
                               edate > "2005-01-01" & edate < "2009-12-31" ~ "2005-2009",
                               edate > "2010-01-01" & edate < "2014-12-31" ~ "2010-2014",
                               edate > "2015-01-01" & edate < "2019-12-31" ~ "2015-2019",
                               edate > "2020-01-01" ~ "2020-2022")
  ) %>% 
  summarise(pol = mean(pol), .by = c(region, year_fctr))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   region   year_fctr     pol
#>   <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 Northern 1990-1994 0.0123 
#> 2 Northern 1995-1999 0.0123 
#> 3 Northern 2000-2004 0.00944
#> 4 Northern 2005-2009 0.00773
#> 5 Northern 2010-2014 0.00878
#> 6 Northern 2015-2019 0.00836
#> 7 Northern 2020-2022 0.00943

Created on 2024-12-18 with reprex v2.1.1

Yes, I have done exactly what you said and that error pops up about quickdf (I actually do not know why is doing that, i do not even know what quickdf does, I have never used it).

The dataframe is the same one as before. I have changed nothing

Do you have a file named .RData in your default working directory? If yes, close RStudio, delete that file and restart RStudio.

Yes, I have deleted the .Rdata file from my current working directory and the error keeps on popping. Also, tried ungrouping the dataframe before doing the code above (hence, taking out the ungroup since there are already no groups) and still no use.

Is there anything else that I can redo to get what I want without being bugged (maybe not using dplyr)? Because I have been trying for almost 4 hours to save the code and it is quite tiresom.

@Th3W31rd0 I don't know, the code above works as expected with the data you have posted. I don't believe the problem is with dplyr, though. Can you post what packages you are loading and the exact code since the start of the session? If you are reading the data from file, etc? Try to post a minimal working example reproducing the error.

As @VinceGreg has pointed it out, I loaded a package that triggered the quickdf, in this case the plyr package. Thank you for the help @RuiBarradas.
